# Changing Win32 UI code from GDI/GDI+ to Direct2D

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi, direct2d

In my Win32/C++ application I have some UI elements that are drawn using GDI+, its using typical commands such as draw an image (from resources), lines, paths, fills etc

I want to change this to use Direct2D to make it a bit snappier and potentially take advantage of effects like blurs/shadows.

I've got most things working using a ID2D1HwndRenderTarget and changed my code to keep things like brushes and pens unless the target needs to be re-created. So far I'm pretty pleased with the results, not only does it seem to perform better but also things like text and rounded rectangles are better quality.

I've got a bit of an issue using a ID2D1Bitmap though. The images I use for buttons are stored in my apps resources as a strip of images, the code indexes into this strip to draw the correct images for the button.

I'm using some MSDN code [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-load-a-bitmap-from-a-resource) to load the resource into a ID2D1Bitmap, I've noticed though that on some of the buttons the neighbouring images seems to spill over. Its almost like the image has been scaled up and then scaled down leaving some artifacts. The loaded ID2D1Bitmap is reporting as the correct size though.

My application is per monitor DPI aware and all the UI code scales correctly, I create my ID2D1HwndRenderTarget using 96 x 96 DPI though as my code is already scaling the geometry of the buttons etc. So if the display is 150% DPI I'm loading images of 48 x 48 (a a strip) and drawing them as 48 x 48.

Secondly I want to draw the bitmap grey scaled when the element is disabled, It seems I can easily draw the image with transparency by changing the opacity but I can't see how to draw it grey scaled. My searching has found there are Direct2D effects but this uses a completely different drawing system (ID2D1DeviceContext) which seems over kill for what I want to do.

Any help appreciated.
Rob

To check the ID2D1Bitmap was the correct size I tried saving it as a PNG but I couldn't figure the code out to do that :(

Comment: Explaining code issues with english language only is a dead end. It really depends on your code.  You should share a minimal reproducing sample or post it on the internet https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example PS: To change to grayscale you need to use a Direct2D effect https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/grayscale-effect and to save a D2D1 bitmap you must use WIC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/save-direct2d-content-to-an-image-file

Comment: Related: Don't create a HWND render target. Instead, you create a ID2D1DeviceContext.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I realise a code example would be better but its a big project, I'll see about producing a smaller version.

Comment: I have started looking at using the ID2D1DeviceContext instead but my initial attempt didn't work, I'll have another look at it